# How to set null to a specific property of json?

Tags: json, vb.net

I've create a json that save the settings of a business logic of my company. Now the problem's that if a day is not working I should have in the json this structure:

```
{"monday":{"start":"09:00","end":"19:00","breaks":[{"start":"10:30","end":"10:40"},{"start":"15:30","end":"16:40"}]},"tuesday":null,"...
```

How you can see `monday` have a start and end working period, and also have a `breaks` the rapresents the not working hours time slot. Anyway the result that I get from my code is this:

```
{"monday":{"start":"09:00","end":"19:00","breaks":[]},"tuesday":{"start":null,"end":null,"breaks":[]},
```

`tuesday` is a no working day so I want achieve to get the json at the top as I shown. This is my code:

```
Public Class WorkDay            'working day

    <JsonProperty("start")>
    Public Property starttime As String
    <JsonProperty("end")>
    Public Property endtime As String 
    Public Property breaks As New List(Of Break)

End Class

Public Class Break              'Breaks time slot

    <JsonProperty("start")>
    Public Property starttime As String
    <JsonProperty("end")>
    Public Property endtime As String

End Class

Public Class WorkWeek           'Class for working days

    Public Property monday As WorkDay
    Public Property tuesday As WorkDay
    Public Property wednesday As WorkDay
    Public Property thursday As WorkDay
    Public Property friday As WorkDay
    Public Property saturday As WorkDay
    Public Property sunday As WorkDay

    'Instance

    Public Sub New()
        monday = New WorkDay
        tuesday = New WorkDay
        wednesday = New WorkDay
        thursday = New WorkDay
        friday = New WorkDay
        saturday = New WorkDay
        sunday = New WorkDay
    End Sub

End Class
```

The class `WorkDay` rapresent the each day as `monday, tuesday, wednesday etc...`. I've also the `break` class for the breaks time slot. And a list of days in the class `WorkWeek`. Now I valorize a certain day of `json` like this:

```
WorkWeek.tuesday.starttime = tuesday_start.Text
WorkWeek.tuesday.endtime = tuesday_end.Text
```

Each days are in a `select stament` like this:

```
For Each c As CheckBox In GroupBox2.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)

        If c.Checked = True Then

            'Check working day

            Select Case c.Name

                Case "monday"

                    WorkWeek.monday.starttime = monday_start.Text
                    WorkWeek.monday.endtime =monday_end.Text

                Case "tuesday"

                    WorkWeek.tuesday.starttime = tuesday_start.Text
                    WorkWeek.tuesday.endtime = tuesday_end.Text

 'Generating..
Dim jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WorkWeek)
```

the `checked` property rapresent the working day, infact my operators can uncheck the not working day. So my code valorize only the workin day. I want to know how I can set `"tuesday":null,"` instead of `"tuesday":{"start":null,"end":null,"breaks":[]}` if tuesday is a not working day. Ideas?

Comment: Where's your code that's generating that JSON?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I update the post, sorry I've missing to add this

Comment: Would it work to just set the EndTime to the StartTime and interpret that in code?

Comment: Then remove the code in Sub New and add lots of checks to create them when they are Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the desired result is to get rid of the `WorkWeek` class and use a dictionary in its place.  In another question you deserialize the data to one to use it as a collection anyway.  Thus:

```
' or use a string array to enforce the name and casing
Public Enum WkDays
    sunday
    monday
    tuesday
    wednesday
    thursday
    friday
    saturday
End Enum

Dim wrkwk As New Dictionary(Of WkDays, WorkDay)    
For Each v As WkDays In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(WkDays))
    wrkwk.Add(v, New WorkDay)
Next
```

It is important to initialize the collection with new, empty WorkDay object so you are not having to check for Nothing everywhere.  For this you might use a function to be sure it always happens.  This version uses a string array for the keys:

```
Private Function GetNewWorkWeek() As Dictionary(Of String, WorkDay)
    Dim days = {"sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
                "thursday", "friday", "saturday"}

    Dim wrkwk As New Dictionary(Of String, WorkDay)
    ' add new, empty WorkDay objects
    For Each d As String In days
        wrkwk.Add(d, New WorkDay)
    Next
    Return wrkwk
End Function

' usage:
Dim wrkwk = GetNewWorkWeek()
```

Since it might be most normal for 5 or 7 days to be present/specified, by initializing it with empty `WorkDay` objects, you dont have to have `If x IsNot Nothing` sprinkled all over your code.  Rather than having to check and create workdays, get the one from the dictionary to work with:

```
' get a workday to work with
Dim wd As WorkDay = wrkwk(WkDays.sunday)
wd.starttime = "08:00"
wd.endtime = "17:30"
Dim b As New Break
b.starttime = "10:05"
b.endtime = "10:20"
wd.breaks.Add(b)
' etc
```

For holidays, you could remove that workday but then it just wouldnt be in the list, to make it show "null" make it `Nothing`:

```
wrkwk(WkDays.tuesday) = Nothing

Dim jstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrkwk)
```

The result:

```
{
"sunday": {
    "start": "08:00",
    "end": "17:30",
    "breaks": [{
        "start": "10:05",
        "end": "10:20"
    }, {
        "start": "14:05",
        "end": "14:20"
    }]
},
"monday": {
   ...
},
"tuesday": null,
"wednesday": {
```

Naturally it would deserialize back into a dictionary just fine.  There are several ways to go about it and work with it. The customer converter is a good idea too.

You should at least consider simply removing the `tuesday` object in such a case.  It is easier to test this:

```
If myWorkWeek.ContainsKey(WkDays.tusday) Then...
```

rather than this everywhere (even if you have data for 364 days per year, since ONE could be null, all your code has to account for that!):

```
If myWorkWeek(n) IsNot Nothing Then...
```

Comment: When I try to add a value, for example: Dim wd As WorkDay = wrkwk(WkDays.sunday) I get: the specified key was not present in the database

Comment: Sounds like you missed the For/Each loop.  Hold the mouse over `wrkwk` and it should show what is in it.  That is not "adding a value" BTW, but getting an object from the collection

Comment: Uhm, this is my code: http://pastebin.com/j95xfVuV what is wrong? I'm trying to add a day to json if the user has valorized it.

Comment: No.  Since it is presumably normal for there to be 7 workdays per week, you want to add 7 blank ones *like I did in the answer*.  That part is not in your code.  THEN for the exception like the tuesday, you set just that one WorkDay to Nothing so it shows null.  The For Loop has nothing to do with users, but everything to do with initializing the collection

Comment: I edited the code with your suggest: http://pastebin.com/C8u3wpS3 but same error appear, what is wrong now?

Comment: On what line?  Did you change the `GetNewWorkWeek` function to use the `WkDays` enum?  You should also turn on Option Strict, without it there could be any number of FUBAR things in your code you dont even know about.  Otherwise it looks mostly correct...in the DGV loop, you *can* just do: `wrkwk(WkDays.monday).breaks.Add(b)` you dont have to fetch the WorkDay object from the collection for small things.

Comment: on this line:  Dim wd As WorkDay = wrkwk(WkDays.monday), I also have the option strict on

Comment: *Did you change the `GetNewWorkWeek` function to use the `WkDays` enum?*  That is not a legal function declaration under Option Strict.  Hold the mouse over `wrkwk` and see what is in it...or show your version of `GetNewWorkWeek`

Comment: I just paste your code, anyway, this is my code now: http://pastebin.com/Xg1Tydjg

Comment: You are missing some key concepts...or skipping all my explanations... or just going too fast.  You are creating a *different collection* than you are trying to use...and Option Strict cannot be on.   You are creating a dictionary with a STRING key then trying to access it using the ENUM variety.  This is what it should look like: http://pastebin.com/46YH1U0f

Comment: Sorry but I'm bit rusty with vb.net, anyway, now seems working the problems is that I doesn't get the json that I expected the result is this: http://pastebin.com/ew19rtfd . Noticed that some TextBox (hours) doesn't contain any value, are just empty.

Comment: The default collection will make a json entry for every day.  To null out a day, you need to set that object to Nothing as I *show in the answer*: `wrkwk(WkDays.tuesday) = Nothing`.  If you want null for Tues, Thurs, Sat and Sun, then each of them needs to be set to Nothing.  I hope you are not also worried about the order...

Comment: No the order isn't a problem, anyway, for set Nothing I should do If Textbox3.Text.Lengh > 0 Then 'day insert Else wrkwk(WkDays.tuesday) = Nothing for each day?

Comment: I would add a checkbox they check when that day is a holiday or closed.  `If chkHoliday.Checked Then wrkwk(WkDays.whatever) = Nothing`..or a calendar you have in code disables inputs for Mussolini day or whatever

Comment: And this is a good practice? I mean create 7 checkbox and check whatever of this are checked in the code?

Comment: This is now well off tppic, but how do you tell which day `Textbox3` is for?  Are there 7 StartTime inputs?  it looks like it: `wd.starttime = Setting.tuesday_start.Text`, so why not 7 "Not Open" checkboxes?

Comment: I mean, http://pastebin.com/TXy5upTR is a good way? Thanks for all Plutonix and happy 2016 :)

Comment: actually, you want to set the collection object to `Nothing`, not just the times (if you want the json to show null for the day): `If chkTuesdayClosed.Check Then wrkwk(WkDays.tuesday) = Nothing`.

Comment: There is a misunderstood, I want simple get this result "tuesday":{"start":null,"end":null,"breaks":[]}, If my provider has unchecked the tuesday day 'cause this mean that isn't a working day. Actually I get "tuesday":{"start":"","end":"","breaks":[]} but should be only "tuesday":null,

Comment: Sorry, yes.  the Start/Stop times will be null by default so you dont have to set that.

Comment: No problem, anyway, with your code I get "tuesday":{"start":"","end":"","breaks":[]} why?

Comment: [in this](http://pastebin.com/ew19rtfd) you say that `"tuesday":null,` is the expected.  for empty string to show as null, initialize `WorkDay` like this: `Public Property starttime As String = Nothing`  add `= Nothing` for end time too

Comment: Now I get tuesday":{"start":null,"end":null,"breaks":[]}, when a day is unchecked I did: wd.starttime = Nothing
            wd.endtime = Nothing

Comment: thats what you said you wanted in the comment 5 items ago: `I want simple get this result "tuesday":{"start":null,"end":null,"breaks":[]}`  which is different from the other [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ew19rtfd)

Comment: about what?  If you want the DAY to be null, set it to nothing, if you just want the times to be "null" leave them nothing.  I dont know what the issue is

Comment: The end result is wrong, check here: http://pastebin.com/AYyaadJv for more explaination, thanks and sorry for the misunderstading

Comment: for `"tuesday":null,` use `wrkwk(WkDays.tuesday) = Nothing` as described in the answer.  that is, set the workday object to Nothing

Answer (score 1):

Rowland is correct.

Or you could add your own custom converter:

```
Friend Class WorkWeekConverter
Inherits JsonConverter

Private ReadOnly _type as Type = GetType(WorkWeek)

Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
    Dim ww = DirectCast(value, WorkWeek)
    writer.WriteStartObject()
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.monday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.tuesday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.wednesday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.thursday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.friday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.saturday))
    WriteWorkDay(writer, ww, serializer, NameOf(WorkWeek.sunday))
    writer.WriteEndObject()
End Sub

Private Sub WriteWorkDay(writer As JsonWriter, ww As WorkWeek, serializer As JsonSerializer, dayOfWeek As String)
    Dim prop = _type.GetProperty(dayOfWeek)
    Dim value = DirectCast(prop.GetValue(ww), WorkDay)
    writer.WritePropertyName(dayOfWeek)
    If value?.IsSet Then
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value)
    Else
        serializer.Serialize(writer, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub

Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
    Return objectType = GetType(WorkWeek)
End Function

Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Function

End Class
```

Add add a convenience property to WorkDay, like so:

```
Public Class WorkDay            'working day

<JsonProperty("start")>
Public Property starttime As String
<JsonProperty("end")>
Public Property endtime As String
Public Property breaks As New List(Of Break)

Friend ReadOnly Property IsSet As Boolean
    Get
        Return Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(starttime) AndAlso
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(endtime))
    End Get
End property

End Class
```

You can specify the converter when you serialize your object:

```
Dim s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, new WorkWeekConverter())
```

Which gives you:

{"monday":{"start":"today","end":"today, evening","breaks":[]},"tuesday":null,"wednesday":null,"thursday":null,"friday":null,"saturday":null,"sunday":null}

That is if x equaled:

```
Dim x As New WorkWeek
x.monday.starttime = "today"
x.monday.endtime="today, evening"
```

Comment: @Dillinger Is there any reason this doesn't get an upvote?  The guy wrote you an entire JsonConverter which works and does what you want (except maybe for 1-2 VS2015 things in it).

Answer (score 0):

For the generated JSON to have a `null` for `tuesday`, you'd need the corresponding object on your `WorkWeek` to be `Nothing` - but in your constructor, you're explicitly creating it. you'd want to either create on demand, or clear it when appropriate.